# Gradle Javadoc task without warnings

Tags: java, android, maven, gradle, javadoc

I generate a javadoc .jar file with Gradle for my Android project. I'm using a similar setup like in [this instruction](https://github.com/chrisbanes/gradle-mvn-push).

But I'm getting a lot of warnings that many symbols are missing. I noticed that the javadoc task doesn't find any of my dependencies. How can I add my dependencies to javadoc task's classpath?

Here is my upload task:

```
afterEvaluate { project ->
    uploadArchives {

    //...

    }

    //...

    task androidJavadocs(type: Javadoc) {
        source = android.sourceSets.main.allJava
    }

    task androidJavadocsJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: androidJavadocs) {
        classifier = 'javadoc'
        from androidJavadocs.destinationDir
    }

    //...

    artifacts {
        archives androidSourcesJar
        archives androidJavadocsJar
    }
}
```

There is also [filed bug](https://github.com/chrisbanes/gradle-mvn-push/issues/9), but I'd like to have a solution now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

roman-mazur answered the question in [another issue](https://github.com/chrisbanes/gradle-mvn-push/pull/13) at Github.

There is currently a discussion going on, whether it's the right way. But for the moment adding these lines solved my issue:

```
afterEvaluate {
    javadocs.classpath += files(android.plugin.runtimeJarList)
}
```

Comment: How are you solving this now? `android.plugin.runtimeJarList` is no longer available and `classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))` does not seem to work. I still see the warnings.